# how to rewrite a path in an initializer in Rails 3.2 ( w assets )

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to write that in an initializer in Rails 3.2 with assets mgt

```
Payday::Config.default.invoice_logo = "#{Rails.root}/public/images/store/logo.png"
```

it seems that asset_path("store/logo.png") is not working ..

Comment: short writing for assets pipeline usage w Rails > 3.1

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with what you're trying to do:
First, Rails 3.2 asset_path is pointing to app/assets/ therefore asset_path("images/store/logo.png") is looking in:

```
"#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/store/logo.png"
```

Second, asset_path is available in your views and scss, not in your initializers. The solution to this problem depends a lot on what you're trying to accomplish with that default.invoice_logo. If you provide more context we may be able to help you farther.

Comment: This is a Payday library initializer, written in Rails < 3.1 :
Payday::Config.default.invoice_logo = "#{Rails.root}/public/images/store/logo.png"